# ¿Se puede convertir tablas de Excel a una base de datos mysql?

Tags: mysql, excel

me gustarpia saber si hay alguna forma de convertir tablas de Excel a MySql. Gracias

Comment: Si, hay formas de transferir datos de excel a mysql.

Comment: Buenas, Podrías realizarlo de varias maneras, a través de un lenguaje de programación abriendo el excel, recorriendo sus filas y columnas y convirtiendo los datos a la estructura que se desee en la base de datos. En la documentación oficial de MySQL para desarrolladores tienes la opción desde la propia aplicación de Excel para exportar el excel en una tabla de mysql. Te dejo el link por si te interesa [LINK HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-export.html) Espero que te haya servido de ayuda, saludos!!

Comment: Si gracias por la respuesta, ha sido util.

Comment: Respeto tu criterio, pero si esa es la razón, hay muchas preguntas que merecerían tambien un voto negativo, creo que no sería justo votarles de forma negativa a personas que tienen como intención encontrar respuestas en el ambiente de una comunidad de colaboración.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo @JeanGotopo ; me parece muy toxico acostumbrarse a responder de esa manera (y sobre todo votar negativamente) cuando la intención de quien consulto era obviamente una orientación inicial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer si tienes instalado algún programa tipo `HeidiSQL`, o bien directamente con el `PHPMyAdmin`.

Solo debes **convertir tu excel a un CSV**, te recomiendo que separado por comas.

Una vez tengas el `CSV` desde los programas, puedes configurar las caracteristicas de tu CSV, para realizar la importación.

Otro método para hacerlo es con el SQL, usando esta consulta

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'Ruta donde tengamos el archivo csv'
INTO TABLE table donde deseemos almacenar los datos
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

**FIELDS TERMINATED BY** Hace referencia cuando se ha de terminar un campo.

**ENCLOSED BY** Hace referencia cuando se ha de cerrar un valor.

**LINES TERMINATED BY** Hace referencia cuando la línea del archivo csv termina con un nuevo carácter.

**IGNORE 1 ROWS** Ignora los encabezados del archivo csv.

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Que excelente respuesta! Muchas gracias @Jose Javier Segura. Me es de mucha utilidad!